# How to exit a git hook script if a git command fails?

Tags: git, githooks

I have a `post-receive` git hook:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    if [ -n "$branch" ] && [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
       working_tree="/path/to/working/dir"
       GIT_WORK_TREE=$working_tree git checkout $branch -f
       GIT_WORK_TREE=$working_tree git pull
       <more instructions>
    fi
done
```

How can I check the status of a git command and stop the script from continuing if it fails?

Something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    if [ -n "$branch" ] && [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
       working_tree="/path/to/working/dir"
       GIT_WORK_TREE=$working_tree git checkout $branch -f
       GIT_WORK_TREE=$working_tree git pull
       if [ <error conditional> ]
           echo "error message"
           exit 1
       fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Run it with `/bin/bash -e` (or `set -e` == `set -o errexit`) and the shell will do it automatically for you whenever an unchecked command fails.

Comment: @PSkocik `-e` is generally discouraged because of its unintuitive semantics. See [Why does set -e not work inside () ||](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/why-does-set-e-not-work-inside).

Comment: @hvd Yeah, that absolutely sucks about `set -e`, but I still think simple shell scripts should be `set -e` by default. Too bad one can't rely on it in libraryish shell functions, exactly because of the behavior you mention. :(

Comment: It's worth noting here that exiting the post-receive function has no effect on the push, and error messages from post-receive may also be entirely invisible.  A post-receive script usually has to use something that smells like `syslog` to capture problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I check the status of a git command and stop the script from continuing if it fails?

The same way you check the status of any shell command: by looking at the return code.  You can inspect the value of the shell variable `$?` after the command exits, as in:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=$working_tree git pull
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

Or by using the command itself as part of a conditional, as in:

```
if ! GIT_WORK_TREE=$working_tree git pull; then
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This seems needlessly verbose. `|| exit 1` is enough.

Comment: Not if you want to emit some sort of useful error message (which the OP is doing in the question).

Comment: And which you aren't doing in your answer. If you want to emit a useful error message, I'd go with `||`, but in combination with a shell function myself: something along the lines of `|| fail "command failed"`, with `fail() { echo "error: $1" >&2; exit 1; }`. This doesn't distract as much when you're reading the script later.